# Multiple LAGs to total a LEAD

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how to go about this. Here is how my data is structured:

```
DATE:                Amount                ID
3/5/2018             0                     ABC
3/7/2018             500                   ABC   
3/9/2018             0                     ABC  
3/15/2018            0                     ABC
3/21/2018            500                   ABC
3/21/2018            -1000                 ABC
4/5/2018             0                     DEF
4/7/2018             0                     DEF  
4/9/2018             600                   DEF 
4/15/2018            0                     DEF    
4/21/2018            600                   DEF
4/21/2018            -1200                 DEF
```

I am looking to pull the dates a positive amount is indicated, and when two (or more) of those amounts hit a total (indicated with a negative amount). THEN, id like to see a difference from the first date, to the applied date (negative amount)

So ABC would be 3/7/2018 to 3/21/2018 for 14 days, DEF would be 4/9 to 4/21 fo 12 days, etc

I feel like it might be a row partition, but I cannot figure out how to do it when it could span multiple months with multiple amounts.

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Please show a sample output in table form

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select id, min(date)mindate, max(date)maxdate, datediff(d, min(date), max(date)) days
from #temp
where amount>0
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*, (grp_amount + amount) as first_difference
from (select t.*,
             min(amount) over (partition by id, grp) as grp_amount,
             row_number() over (partition by id, grp, sign(amount) order by date) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   min(case when amount < 0 then date end) over (partition by id order by date desc) as grp
            from t
     ) t
where amount > 0 and seqnum = 1;
```

What is this doing?

For each record, it assigns a `grp`.  This is the date of the next negative value.  Then within the group, it determines the negative value and the first positive record.  The calculation is based on this informaiton.